# Reactive UI Apply multiple filters

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am currently building a WPF application (my first one) and one of the views is a DataGrid with lots of columns and lots of filters.

My problem is with the filtering, i have managed to get it working by using `this.WhenAnyValue` and `CreateDerivedCollection` methods, however when i add more and more filters, they are independent of each other.

I can see what my problem is, for each "filter" i'm essentially overwriting the current filter, but i'm unsure how to correct it.

My thinking is i'm going to have to put all the filters into the `this.WhenAnyValue` method, but i notice this caps out at 12 properties, and i have a lot more than that.

Here is the code to initialize the ViewModel and the filters.

```
public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    try
    {
        _mortgageTypes = default(MortgageType)
            .ToDictionary()
            .Select(mt => new ComboBoxMortgageType(mt.Key, mt.Value))
            .ToList();

        using (var db = new MortgageDbContext())
        {
            LenderNames =
                await (from l in db.Lenders
                        select new ComboBoxLenderName(l.Id, l.Name)
                    ).ToListAsync();

            LenderNames.Insert(0, new ComboBoxLenderName(Guid.Empty, "None"));

            _rootList = new ReactiveList<LendersView>(await (from l in db.Lenders
                select new LendersView
                {
                    Citizenship = l.Citizenship.GetDescription(),
                    CriteriaUrl = l.CriteriaUrl,
                    Id = l.Id,
                    FirstTimeBuyer = l.FirstTimeBuyer,
                    MaximumAge = l.MaximumAge,
                    MinimumIncome = l.MinimumIncome,
                    Name = l.Name,
                    NewBuilds = l.NewProperty.AcceptBuyToLet || l.NewProperty.AcceptResidential,
                    PrimaryContact = l.PrimaryContactInformation.ToString(),
                    RatesUrl = l.RatesUrl,
                    SecondaryContact = l.SecondaryContactInformation.ToString(),
                    SelfEmployment = l.SelfEmployment.Accept,
                    SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome = l.SelfEmployment.MinimumIncome,
                    SelfEmploymentYearsBooks = l.SelfEmployment.YearsBooks
                }).ToListAsync());
        }

        this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SelectedLender)
            .Subscribe(_ => { Lenders = _rootList.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, x => SelectedLender == Guid.Empty || x.Id == SelectedLender); });

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.AcceptSelfEmployment, x => x.SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome, x => x.SelfEmploymentYearsBooks)
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                Lenders = _rootList.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x,
                    x => (!AcceptSelfEmployment || x.SelfEmployment == AcceptSelfEmployment) &&
                        (SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome == default || x.SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome >= SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome) &&
                        (SelfEmploymentYearsBooks == default || x.SelfEmploymentYearsBooks >= SelfEmploymentYearsBooks));
            });
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After Glenns' helpful response, this is the code i have currently.

```
public SearchViewModel()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    _rootList = new SourceList<LendersView>();

    var lenderFilter = this.WhenValueChanged(x => x.SelectedLender)
        .Select(LenderNamePredicate);

    var loader =_rootList
        .Connect()               
        .Filter(lenderFilter)
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Bind(out _lenders)
        .Subscribe();
    Task.Run(InitializeAsync).ContinueWith(res => _rootList.AddRange(res.Result));
    _cleanUp = new CompositeDisposable(loader);
}

private Func<LendersView, bool> LenderNamePredicate(Guid selectedLender)
{
    if (selectedLender == Guid.Empty)
    {
        return lender => true;
    }

    return lender => lender.Id == selectedLender;
}
```

Which does seem to work fine, however i'm struggling with the composite filter that i have in this slither of code

```
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.AcceptSelfEmployment, x => x.SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome, x => x.SelfEmploymentYearsBooks)
        .Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            Lenders = _rootList.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x,
                x => (!AcceptSelfEmployment || x.SelfEmployment == AcceptSelfEmployment) &&
                    (SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome == default || x.SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome >= SelfEmploymentMinimumIncome) &&
                    (SelfEmploymentYearsBooks == default || x.SelfEmploymentYearsBooks >= SelfEmploymentYearsBooks));
        });
```

Is there anything equivalent in dynamic data? Also do i really need to add a separate function for each filter every time? I'm just thinking i'm going to have about 30-40 filters in the end and a function for each one will just bloat the view model even more.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: The ReactiveList/ReactiveDerivedList is being removed from ReactiveUI and we recommend you use DynamicData instead. See https://reactiveui.net/blog/2018/08/reactiveui-succession-update for details.

Comment: Nice thing about DynamicData in your case also is you can apply the Filter() method multiple times which would solve your issue.